# Checkbox no visible en restricciones por transportistas de las preferencias de pago de Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop1.7

Tengo la versión 1.7.8.11 y no puedo seleccionar transportistas en las preferencias de pago, aparecen con un doble guión en vez de aparecer el checkbox.

[image: Prestashop restricciones por transportisa]

He desinstalado varias veces los transportistas y vueltos a instalar pero no hay forma. Tampoco veo la diferencia entre el 31, que tiene los checkboxes visibles, y los otros. ¿Cuál es la razón por la que no aparecen los checkboxes?